# Unable to create AWS Lambda Function using serverless framework - AccessDeniedException Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to run the serverless "Python HTTP API" lambda example. It generated the following `serverless.yaml` file. I just added the region as well as profile that it should pick up that I have configured on my machine using `aws configure`

```yaml
service: aws-python-http-api-project
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  stage: dev
  region: ap-south-1
  profile: lambda-user

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get
```

The `lambda-user` aws user has the following permissions -

1. AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator
2. AmazonS3FullAccess
3. AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
4. AWSLambda_FullAccess
5. AWSLambdaRole
6. CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
7. IAMFullAccess

You can notice that in the screenshot below
[image: Permissions]

However, when I run `serverless deploy` it always fails to create the Lambda Function

```bash
serverless deploy

Deploying aws-python-http-api-project to stage dev (ap-south-1)
Warning: Not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction for at least one of the lambda functions. Deployment will not be skipped even if service files did not change.

✖ Stack aws-python-http-api-project-dev failed to deploy (74s)
Environment: darwin, node 17.2.0, framework 3.28.1, plugin 6.2.3, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, "lambda-user" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
CREATE_FAILED: HelloLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
Resource handler returned message: "Service returned error code AccessDeniedException (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: d7ea8db6-1a2f-4035-ae12-3c8ce1a7eea0)" (RequestToken: fef6b145-da36-d147-337d-f8c719d5dbe5, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

View the full error: https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=ap-south-1#/stack/detail?stackId=arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aap-south-1%3A030740437667%3Astack%2Faws-python-http-api-project-dev%2Fcea57d30-c416-11ed-bdb3-023ecd5655ae
```

And the CloudFormation Stack Events look like this -
[image: CloudFormation Stack]

As you can see, this is failing to create the Lambda Function

```bash
Resource handler returned message: "Service returned error code AccessDeniedException (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: d7ea8db6-1a2f-4035-ae12-3c8ce1a7eea0)" (RequestToken: fef6b145-da36-d147-337d-f8c719d5dbe5, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)
```

I have been trying to debug the whole day. But at this point in time, I am totally out of ideas! Any suggestions are helpful.

Thanks!

***EDIT***

The issue was more to do with my account being suspended for some suspicious activities. Their automated system had flagged my account as compromised, so I had to contact their support team, which asked a bunch of questions & then restored all the services.

Comment: Does `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile lambda-user` yield the expected IAM user `arn:aws:iam::1111222333:user/lambda-user`?

Comment: @jarmod, yes it does

Comment: If you log in to the AWS console as that IAM user and use the Lambda console, can you create a hello-world Lambda function in the ap-south-1 region? Any chance your organization has an SCP restricting your IAM user's permissions?

Comment: When I create a lambda function in the console using the IAM user, it just keeps running. In the network tab, I can see that for the POST request to https://lambda.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions, I get a 403 response.

Not too sure about the SCP restricting IAM permissions. The IAM user gets the error - "Your request has a problem. Please see the following details. - Your account is not a member of an organization."

Comment: Is this account part of an AWS Organization? Can you check SCPs with the org admin?

Comment: This is my personal account. Also, I just checked that the root user gets the same response

Comment: Is the account in good standing financially (not suspended)? Have you reached any Lambda quota limits? Not sure if the latter will cause 403 tbh but may be worth checking.

Comment: Recently, it was suspended due to security reasons. It turned out their system suspended the account without good reason. A couple of days ago, they restored it.

Comment: So if AWS restored the account but you can't use the services, it sounds like you need to submit a support ticket to AWS.

Comment: Thanks! I have submitted a ticket

Comment: @AdityaMishra Did you manage to fix this? I am getting the same issue right now (get function warning followed by a failure)

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne yes I was able to fix this. The issue was more to do with my account being suspended rather than any issue with the serverless code. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @AdityaMishra Appreciated!